# How can we cache Svg's using SvgUri in react-native-svg?

Tags: react-native, caching, react-native-svg

I'm using `SvgUri` component from the `react-native-svg` package. Is there any way to cache these SVG's?

I found this [issue on github](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/1328), but the mentioned solution there didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the same problem, the issue on GitHub is closed, but for me, it is not a "clean" solution. The cache support should be implemented in the library itself.

After some hours, I found this package which works very well: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image

If you're installing this in a [bare React Native app](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/overview/), you should also follow [these additional installation instructions](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-50/packages/expo-image).

By default, it includes a cache and store it in the "disk", you can change if you want with: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/#cachepolicy

A simple change will optimize your code and application, like:

```
<SvgUri width="50" height="50" uri="url here" />
```

to

```
<Image
   style={{
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  }}
  source="url here"
  cachePolicy="memory-disk"
/>
```

And off course

```bash
npm remove react-native-svg
```